# Голосование за переоткрытие

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Когда вопрос закрывают как некачественный, кажется неразумным давать возможность топикстартеру голосовать за переоткрытие.

Comment: И ... в чем ваше [предложение] ?

Comment: Возможно ли технически запретить топикстартерам голосовать за переоткрытие своих вопросов?

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", воспользуйтесь ей и дополните вопрос

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не согласен. Думаю, предполагается, что когда автор исправит вопрос, он как раз может проголосовать и таким образом отправить вопрос в очередь проверок.

Comment: Согласен, только когда кто-то вносить правку в закрытый вопрос, он вроде и так отправляется в очередь.

Comment: Только если он достаточно свежий - вроде до 2 или 4 дней. Если позже, то вроде нет.